# SELECT COUNT(id) doesn't give me the right value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

hello I'm on the finishline of writing a chat script. The only thing left is to compare how many messeges had the user seen with the total number in the database. Now the following line doesn't seem to work and I've been staring at it for an hour and can't find the cause.

```
$count = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(id) as total FROM konsultaciq WHERE cat = "'.$_SESSION['key'].'" ');
echo count(total);
```

The echo gives me a value of "1", when there are 8 entries in the database under that "cat"

Comment: Have you fetched the result?

Comment: First, `total` should either be defined as a constant or it should be `$total`. In either case, you aren't assigning a value to it. Secondly, the MySQL extension is deprecated. **Stop using it right now** and use PDO or MySQLi instead

Comment: Shouldn't that be `echo $count(total);` or `echo $total;`, or `echo $count;`? Try one of those. You have `$count` as your variable but not echoing it correctly.

Comment: You need to fetch the array `$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($count);` and then echo the value `echo $result['total'];`

Comment: @Fred None of those will do anything with the above code. In fact, `$count(total)` is a syntax error

Comment: @Phil Thanks Phil. I'm learning MySQL also, so I did not know those for a fact, hence my "comments".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your code as below.

```
$count = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(id) as total FROM konsultaciq WHERE cat = "'.$_SESSION['key'].'" ');
$res=mysql_fetch_array($count);
echo $res[0]; // it gives actual value of total
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$count = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(id) as total FROM konsultaciq WHERE cat = "'.$_SESSION['key'].'" ');
$arr = mysql_fetch_array($count);
echo $arr['total'];
```

Use above code. As you have not fetch the data by using `mysql_fetch_*` and if you will use the count function then it will show the 1 because of it is fetching one row.

`count` function is used to count the number of elements in array in PHP and there will be only one element.

so use `$arr['total']` to get the value of total count of the query.

> NOTE: mysql_* has been deprecated in the PHP's latest version. So use
>   the mysqli_* or PDO.

Comment: It's better to use `mysqli()` or pdo, since this extension is deprecated.

Comment: @mattosmat yes I know it. I used the PDO. but OP is asking in mysql that's why give the answer in mysql_*. and why downvote.

Comment: @BrokenHeartღ I agree with you and have a point about the OP's question being **MySQL** related, as the OP did not ask for MySQLi alternative.

Comment: @Fred Ok, I will addedd a note in the answer to use the mysqli or PDO.

Comment: @BrokenHeartღ Don't get me wrong, I agree with what you said in your comment above to `mattosmat`. I didn't say anything about you adding it. It is the OP's fault, not yours. You simply answered the question correctly, related to MySQL code posted in question. ;-)

Comment: @Fred thanks. But I will remember to add such note next time. it is a good practice. again thanks.

Comment: @BrokenHeartღ You're quite welcome, cheers. I'm in the learning process (DB), and will not be using MySQL, but MySQLi or PDO as strongly suggested from the answers I see here on SO.

Answer (score 3):

You should **not** be using the MySQL extension. Here's an example using PDO instead

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=your_db_name;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT COUNT(1) FROM konsultaciq WHERE cat = ?');
$stmt->bindParam(1, $_SESSION['key']);
$stmt->execute();

echo $stmt->fetchColumn();
```